# Update a column using Subquery in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an EMPLOYEE table below:

```
EMP_ID     DEPT_ID
101        1
102        2
103        3
104        1
```

And a DEPARTMENT table as:

```
DEPT_ID  COUNTS
1   
2   
3
```

I want to write a query which would count the number of Employee that belong to a department and store it into Department column table so the Department table will look like:

```
DEPT_ID  COUNTS
1         2
2         1
3         1
```

The solution is

```
update department p
    set counts = (select count(*) from EMPLOYEE e where p.dept_id = e.dept_id);
```

But i really dont understand how it works internally  How does it know which dept ids in DEPARTMENT it has to set counts to. what exactly does this subquery return "select count(*) from EMPLOYEE e where p.dept_id = e.dept_id"

Comment: Google "correlated subquery"

Comment: Why the mysql tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called *correlated* subquery:

This is your query:

```
update department p
set counts = (select count(*) from EMPLOYEE e where p.dept_id = e.dept_id);
```

So, the inner query get executed based on the outer query (i.e. has `department` table). If, your outer query has total 3 records then, inner query (i.e. has `EMPLOYEE` table) will get execute three times.

In your scenario, you have mapped the queries with `dept_id` from outer query, so this will look up into inner query (i.e. `EMPLOYEE` table) and get the counts based on `dept_id`.